# Get device ID - Express

Tags: android, express

I'm building mobile application.

Stack:

Server: **Express**

Client: **Android**

I need to extract unique id for the device or something unique but on server side so not to be provided in the request body from the client side - maybe some unique headers or smt like this

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What will you create a unique information without the user or device information?

Answer (score 0):

```
fun getDeviceId(): String {
    return try {
        val deviceId =
            "35" + Build.BOARD.length % 10 + Build.BRAND.length % 10 + Build.CPU_ABI.length % 10 + Build.DEVICE.length % 10 + Build.MANUFACTURER.length % 10 + Build.MODEL.length % 10 + Build.PRODUCT.length % 10
        var serial: String? = null
        try {
            serial = Build::class.java.getField("SERIAL")[null].toString()
            return UUID(deviceId.hashCode().toLong(), serial.hashCode().toLong()).toString()
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            serial = "serial" // some value
        }
        val id = UUID(deviceId.hashCode().toLong(), serial.hashCode().toLong()).toString()
        if (id.length > 40) id.substring(0, 40) else id
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        ""
    }
}
```